# Replica set MongoDB on VPS Docker-compose

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose, vps

I have an application on node.js that requires MongoDB with replica set. I created docker-compose.yml and it works great locally.

The problem is that when I run this file on the VPS, I cannot connect to it.
Connection example:
`mongodb://6.255.60.110:27017,6.255.60.110:27018,6.255.60.110:27019/?replicaSet=rs0`
(I changed real IP)

MongoDB Compass throws an error: `connect ECONNREFUSED 6.255.60.110:27017`
[Result command `docker ps`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2GWL0.png)

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  mongo1:
    image: mongo:latest
    command: ["--replSet", "rs0", "--bind_ip_all", "--port", "27017"]
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
    healthcheck:
      test: echo "try { rs.status() } catch (err) { rs.initiate({_id:'rs0',members:[{_id:0,host:'host.docker.internal:27017',priority:1},{_id:1,host:'host.docker.internal:27018',priority:0.5},{_id:2,host:'host.docker.internal:27019',priority:0.5}]}) }" | mongosh --port 27017 --quiet
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 30s
      start_period: 0s
      start_interval: 1
      retries: 30
    volumes:
      - "mongo1_data:/data/db"
      - "mongo1_config:/data/configdb"

  mongo2:
    image: mongo:latest
    command: ["--replSet", "rs0", "--bind_ip_all", "--port", "27018"]
    ports:
      - 27018:27018
    extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
    volumes:
      - "mongo2_data:/data/db"
      - "mongo2_config:/data/configdb"

  mongo3:
    image: mongo:latest
    command: ["--replSet", "rs0", "--bind_ip_all", "--port", "27019"]
    ports:
      - 27019:27019
    extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
    volumes:
      - "mongo3_data:/data/db"
      - "mongo3_config:/data/configdb"

volumes:
  mongo1_data:
  mongo2_data:
  mongo3_data:
  mongo1_config:
  mongo2_config:
  mongo3_config:
```

I also forwarded ports from 16797 to 27017 it did not help

When I started 1 mongoDB server on VPS I can connect to it
Example: `docker run mongo --port 27017`

I also followed the instructions from the Internet and added them manually:

https://www.mongodb.com/compatibility/deploying-a-mongodb-cluster-with-docker

https://github.com/prisma/prisma/discussions/18958#discussioncomment-7269305

and also many other

Answer (score 0):

I have a bit different but a working solution for MongoDB replica-set in docker-compose. (There are some useful comments in the compose file)

**docker-compose.yml:**

```yaml
version: "3.8"

services:
  mongo1:
    image: mongo:4.4.5
    hostname: mongo1
    networks:
      - mongo_net
    # The following variables won't be used due to set entrypoint section
    # The replica-set sets automatically, but the admin user has to be set
    # only one time when you use new deploy. I guess it can be automated, but I didn't have time for it...
    # Eg.:
    #    docker exec -it <docker-container-id> mongo
    #    use admin
    #    db.createUser({ user: "admin", pwd: "admin_pwd", roles: [ { role: "userAdminAnyDatabase", db: "admin" } ] })
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE=test_db
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=admin
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=admin_pwd
      - MONGO_DATA_DIR=/data/db
    volumes:
      - mongo-1:/data/db
      - ./docker-entrypoint-mongo.sh:/data/docker-entrypoint.sh
    # Probably the expose is not needed because the services can
    # communicate on any port inside Docker Network.
    expose:
      - 27017
    entrypoint:
      - bash
      - -c
      - |
        chmod +x /data/docker-entrypoint.sh
        exec /data/docker-entrypoint.sh
    healthcheck:
      test: test $$(echo "rs.initiate({_id:'my-replica-set',members:[{_id:0,host:\"mongo1:27017\"},{_id:1,host:\"mongo2:27017\"}]}).ok || rs.status().ok" | mongo --quiet ) -eq 1
      interval: 10s
      start_period: 30s

  mongo2:
    image: mongo:4.4.5
    hostname: mongo2
    networks:
      - mongo_net
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE=test_db
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=admin
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=admin_pwd
      - MONGO_DATA_DIR=/data/db
    volumes:
      - mongo-2:/data/db
      - ./docker-entrypoint-mongo.sh:/data/docker-entrypoint.sh
    expose:
      - 27017
    entrypoint:
      - bash
      - -c
      - |
        chmod +x /data/docker-entrypoint.sh
        exec /data/docker-entrypoint.sh

volumes:
  mongo-1:
  mongo-2:

networks:
  mongo_net: {}
```

**docker-entrypoint-mongo.sh:**

```bash
mongod "--enableMajorityReadConcern" "false" "--journal" "--dbpath" "/data/db" "--replSet" "my-replica-set" "--bind_ip_all"
```

I am used it from another (Python) service in the same network:

```py
self.__mongo_client = pymongo.MongoClient(
    host=["mongo1:27017", "mongo2:27017"],
    username="admin",
    password="admin_pwd",
    replicaset="my-replica-set",
)
```

But the "pure" connection string should be in this case:

```
mongodb://mongo1:27017,mongo2:27017/?replicaSet=my-replica-set
```